# subprocess checkouput OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess

Below is example code:

```
from subprocess import check_output
list1 = ['df', 'df -h']
for x in list1:
    output = check_output([x])
```

Getting below error for list1 of dh -h value.

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
  process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

what is best method to read linux command output's in python2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide `check_output` arguments as a list.
This works:

```
from subprocess import check_output
list1 = ['df', 'df -h']
for x in list1:
    output = check_output(x.split())
```

Comment: Please note you have to add `shell=True` as an argument of `check_output` to execute a shell command.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `delegator` written by kennethreitz, with his package https://github.com/kennethreitz/delegator.py, you can simply do， and both the API and output is cleaner:

```
import delegator

cmds = ['df', 'df -h']
for cmd in cmds:
    p = delegator.run(cmd)
    print(p.out)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options with this situation, for ways of passing a `cmd` and `args`:

```
# a list broken into individual parts, can be passed with `shell=False
['cmd', 'arg1', 'arg2', ... ]
# a string with just a `cmd`, can be passed with `shell=False`
'cmd`
# a string with a `cmd` and `args` 
# can only be passed to subprocess functions with `shell=True`
'cmd arg1 arg2 ...'
```

Just to follow up on [marii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48771286/5943150)s answer. The [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) on python.org have more info on *why* you may want to pick one of a couple of options.

> `args` is required for all calls and **should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names)**. If passing a single string, either `shell` must be `True` (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.

(emphesis added)

While adding `shell=True` would be OK for this, it's recommended to avoid, as changing `'df -h'` to `['df', '-h']` isn't very difficult, and is a good habit to get into, only using the shell if you really need to. As the docs also add, against a *red background* no less:

> **Warning**. 
>   Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an
>   untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to **shell injection**, a
>   serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution.
>   For this reason, the use of `shell=True` is **strongly discouraged** in
>   cases where the command string is constructed from external input